# Is retagging obvious Android questions with the "android" tag discouraged?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are several questions tagged [android-listview](/questions/tagged/android-listview) or [android-asynctask](/questions/tagged/android-asynctask) which could use the generic [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag in addition so they are more easily found.

Is it discouraged or encouraged to add this tag if they have less than five tags?

Personally I would like them to have this tag because I use a bookmark (/unanswered/tagged/android) to find unanswered Android questions. I cannot use the "unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags" tab because I have several other tags that I do not want to have in that list when I am in the mood to answer Android questions.

Or should change my bookmark to include all the `android-*` tags ORed together?

Comment: I believe it should be encouraged; questions related to [tag:android-listview] should *also* be tagged [tag:android], for the exact reasons you mentioned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Retagging to include [android](/questions/tagged/android) on those questions should be *encouraged*.  The [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag currently has over 15,000 followers, while [android-listview](/questions/tagged/android-listview) has 44 and [android-asynctask](/questions/tagged/android-asynctask) has 32.  Questions with *only* either of the latter tags should get a lot more attention with the inclusion of the more popular generic tag.

Comment: What if the question already has 5 tags? Is it still OK to replace one with the popular android tag? Maybe only if the questions seems easy and has not many views for a quite long time?

Comment: @DirkJäckel Yes, I think that should be okay.  If the question needs attention, go ahead and replace one of the less-followed tags with `android`.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, hi there are so many questions with non full android tags, i.e. `drawable` instead of `android-drawable`, first has 1k hits, second one only 76.. retag or not retag?

Comment: @Lumma If a question tagged `drawable` already has the `android` tag then we probably don't need to retag it. Since `android-drawable` only has 76 uses and 1 follower, we can probably just get rid of it.

Answer (score 5):

Adding the [android](/questions/tagged/android) to these would definitely be the correct process.

I just finished adding the [android](/questions/tagged/android) to the [android-listview](/questions/tagged/android-listview) items that were missing it.  I will move on to the [android-asynctask](/questions/tagged/android-asynctask) items

EDIT:

I just finished the 80 questions with the  [android-asynctask](/questions/tagged/android-asynctask) but no [android](/questions/tagged/android).  This should be done.

Answer (score 2):

Would it be possible for anything tagged android-* would automaticaly be tagged [android](/questions/tagged/android) as well. This would help clasification.

Or could you have 'tag groups' that define a 'parent' tag and 'child' tags. This would mean [android](/questions/tagged/android) would be a parent whilst [android-listview](/questions/tagged/android-listview) and [android-asynctask](/questions/tagged/android-asynctask) would be its children. Everything tagged android-asynctask would also be classified/tagged as [android](/questions/tagged/android).